# Linear dependence and independence of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $v_1 = (−1,−1,1,0)$ and $v_2 = (3,0,3,1)$ be two vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. (a) Find a vector $v$ such that the set $\{v_1,v_2,v\}$ is linearly independent. (b) Find real numbers $s,t \in\Bbb R$ such that the vector $v = (−2,1,s,t)$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

The solution I think (a) $v=(n,n,0,0),n\in\Bbb Z$

(b) $s,t = (-3,-1)$.

Please let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Welcome to the website! Can you type out your solution briefly so that we can check? Use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math equations.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into Mathjax after this.  The solution i think a) (n,n,0,0) Where n can be any Integer.         b) s,t = (-3,-1).  Please let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, that is a possible choice for $v$. Note that you need to mention $n\ne0$. And what about part b?

Comment: I edited my comment. Could you please read again

Comment: Your question earlier was lacking context, details like where you found this question, what you tried and where you were stuck. That is why it got downvoted by the community. Now I have added your proposed solution to the body of your question and upvoted the question to counter-act the downvote. Make sure to add your effort in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution to part $(a)$ is almost correct. In order for $v_1,v_2,(n,n,0,0)$ to be linearly independent, $n\ne0$ otherwise $v=0$. You can check that$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&1&0\\3&0&3&1\\n&n&0&0&\end{bmatrix}$$is a full rank matrix for $n\ne0$ by performing the row operations $R_2\to R_2+3R_1,R_3\to R_3+nR_1$ to get

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1&1&0\\0&-3&6&1\\0&0&n&0&\end{bmatrix}$$

---

Let $(-2,1,s,t)=av_1+bv_2=a(-1,-1,1,0)+b(3,0,3,1)$.

So we have $-a+3b=-2,-a+0b=1$. We get $a=b=-1$.

So $s=a+3b=-4,t=b=-1$.

Comment: Yup, -4 and -1 I did a typo up there. I'll be more careful. Thanks!

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. You are welcome @LightoK!